# Deploying Spring Boot to Tomcat 10 produces 404 error

Tags: java, spring-boot, tomcat10

I've followed about 15 different threads on Stack to try and resolve this, but I seem to be hitting a brick wall.

I'm running JDK17 and Tomcat 10.0.22. I have followed a baeldung article for deploying a Spring Boot app on Tomcat, and I'm having no luck at all. I've tried used gradle and maven.

With the provided block commented out, the war runs fine with java -jar spring-boot-deployment.war. However, when activating this line and dragging the war into the web app folder, it doesn't work.

For example, just in spring boot localhost:8080/hello/ works fine
after deploying to Tomcat and going to http://localhost:8080/spring-boot-deployment/hello/ I get `The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.`

I'm not seeing any errors in the Tomcat logs, and the manager says its running. Given how many threads there are on this, it seems to be a pretty poorly documented/understood thing.

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringBootTomcatApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringBootTomcatApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

```java
@RestController
public class TomcatController {

    @GetMapping(value = "/hello")
    public Collection<String> sayHello() {
        return IntStream.range(0, 10)
                .mapToObj(i -> "Hello number " + i)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}
```

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-deployment</artifactId>
    <name>spring-boot-deployment</name>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <groupId>com.baeldung.spring-boot-modules</groupId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.7</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>${artifactId}</finalName>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/conf.properties</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>repackage</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <mainClass>com.baeldung.springbootsimple.SpringBootTomcatApplication</mainClass>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: You will need to downgrade to Tomcat 9.

Comment: Thanks.. I can't believe how much time I wasted on that....